# Qrencode: ignore option flags in a string

Tags: string, qr-code

I have a PGP key stored as a string, and I'm trying to create a QR code of it.

> qrencode -o qrcode.png "$thestring"

But my output is:

> qrencode: unrecognized option '-----BEGIN'

How do I force qrencode to just treat the dashes as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the string with whitespace is a workaround. However, the PGP key will be too long for qrencode, so it's pointless anyways.